# Looping in Pyspark causes sparkException

Tags: loops, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Zeppelin with pyspark.
Before I found the correct way of doing things (Last over a Window), I had a loop that extended the value of a previous row to itself one by one (I know loops are bad practice). However, after running a couple hundred times it fails with a nullPointerException before reaching the best case condition=0.

To get around the error, (before I discovered the last command), I had the loop run a few hundred times for a midpoint condition=1000, dump the results. Run it again with condition=500, rinse and repeat until I hit condition=0.

```py
def extendTarget(myDF, loop, lessThan):
    i = myDF.filter(col("target") == "unknown").count()
    while (i > lessThan):
        cc = loop
        while (cc > 0):
            myDF = myDF.withColumn("targetPrev", lag("target", 1).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("myTime"))) 
            myDF = myDF.withColumn("targetNew", when(col("target") == "unknown", col("targetPrev")).otherwise(col("target")))
            myDF = myDF.select(
            "id",
            "myTime",
            col("targetNew").alias("target"))
            cc = cc - 1
        i = myDF.filter(col("target") == "unknown").count()
        print i
    return myDF

myData = spark.read.load(myPath)
myData = extendTarget(myData, 20, 0)
myData.write.parquet(myPathPart1)
```

I expect it to take a stupid long amount of time (since I'm doing it wrong), but do not expect it to exception out with

```
Output (given inputs (myData, 20, 0)
38160
22130
11375
6625
5085
4522
4216
3936
3662
3419
3202

Error 
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26814.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 32 in stage 1539.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 32.3 in stage 1539.0 (TID XXXX, ip-XXXX, executor 17): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 17 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_XXXX_0001_01_000033 on host: ip-XXXX. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_XXXX_0001_01_000033
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50
.
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2041)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2262)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2211)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2200)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2830)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2829)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2829)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor388.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

(<class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'>, Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling o26814.count.\n', JavaObject id=o26815), <traceback object at 0x7efc521b11b8>)
```

I can only guess that this has something to do with memory or cache. Even though I am reusing all variable names. If it is a memory problem, is there a garbage collect, or clear cache/memory command that I can put beside the print command to allow it to loop forever?

Again I know its bad practice to use loops, especially if they go on for what seems like forever, but sometimes the better\smarter code doesn't present itself when I need it so during the interim I hack it however I can.

Comment: Could you please post the full error message? I assume that the execution plan is getting to large and that you have interrupt it to be able to execute a your slow loop but without the full error message it is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks cronoik, I added in the full error message. Hopefully I didn't censor too much.

Comment: Not seeing "NullPointerException" anywhere in that error...

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide the executor stacktrace, not the driver's

Comment: Good point, I'm not seeing the nullPointer either, I guess the exception changed?? I changed the topic to sparkException. I'm unfortunately unable to give any other error message except the one provided as I only have access to Zeppelin. An explanation or theory as to why would be great, but ultimately I'm looking for a command like clear cache/memory/node or something to allow the command to continue forever if it exists, if it doesn't well... thats an answer too i guess

Comment: Could you please try the following (this will keep the execution plan small): `myDF = myDF.select("id", "myTime", col("targetNew").alias("target")).checkpoint()` (replace the corrosponding line before and and the checkpoint directory before via spark.setCheckpointDir).

Comment: I tested it out and it worked!
The first few times it failed though, mostly due to my misunderstanding of how checkpoint works. Would you like to put your answer as an answer?

Some things I had to figure out that would be nice as part of the answer
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("path/") - to set checkpointPath
myDF.checkpoint() does not work, you have to assign that checkpoint back
myDF = myDF.checkpoint()

Also, I found the nullpointer exception, if I tell the loop to run 200 times before counting it does a nullpointerException and sparkContext ends. (must be restarted)

Comment: Also, having the checkpoint inside each loop caused it to run slowly as it was probably checkpointing every loop run. What really sped it up was putting the checkpoint right before the print, allowing it to loop within memory x amt of times (i used 100) before checkpointing. Thanks cronoik, if you put your answer as an answer I'll mark it my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in a comment by Cronoik

Could you please try the following (this will keep the execution plan small): myDF = myDF.select("id", "myTime", col("targetNew").alias("target")).checkpoint() (replace the corrosponding line before and and the checkpoint directory before via spark.setCheckpointDir). – cronoik Sep 9 at 4:05

I tested it out and it worked! The first few times it failed though, mostly due to my misunderstanding of how checkpoint works. Would you like to put your answer as an answer? Some things I had to figure out that would be nice as part of the answer spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("path/") - to set checkpointPath myDF.checkpoint() does not work, you have to assign that checkpoint back myDF = myDF.checkpoint() Also, I found the nullpointer exception, if I tell the loop to run 200 times before counting it does a nullpointerException and sparkContext ends. (must be restarted) – Ranald Fong Sep 10 at 2:44

Also, having the checkpoint inside each loop caused it to run slowly as it was probably checkpointing every loop run. What really sped it up was putting the checkpoint right before the print, allowing it to loop within memory x amt of times (i used 100) before checkpointing. Thanks cronoik, if you put your answer as an answer I'll mark it my answer! – Ranald Fong Sep 10 at 2:53

Edit: Commenter wanted details

Point is to extend a value from one row until the end, replacing all unknowns

```
| id | time | target |
| a  | 1:00 | 1      |
| a  | 1:01 | unknown|
| a  | .    | .      |
| a  | 5:00 | unknown|
| a  | 5:01 | 2      |
```

to

```
| id | time | target |
| a  | 1:00 | 1      |
| a  | 1:01 | 1      |
| a  | .    | 1      |
| a  | 5:00 | 1      |
| a  | 5:01 | 2      |
```

Code was changed to use Checkpoints

```
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(".../myCheckpointsPath/")
def extendTarget(myDF, loop, lessThan):
    i = myDF.filter(col("target") == "unknown").count()
    while (i > lessThan):
        cc = loop
        while (cc > 0):
            myDF = myDF.withColumn("targetPrev", lag("target", 1).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("myTime"))) 
            myDF = myDF.withColumn("targetNew", when(col("target") == "unknown", col("targetPrev")).otherwise(col("target")))
            myDF = myDF.select(
            "id",
            "myTime",
            col("targetNew").alias("target"))
            cc = cc - 1
        i = myDF.filter(col("target") == "unknown").count()
        print i
        myDF = myDF.checkpoint()
    return myDF

myData = spark.read.load(myPath)
myData = extendTarget(myData, 20, 0)
myData.write.parquet(myPathPart1)
```

At the expense of HDD space for the checkpoints, allows the loop to go on forever! But in general, do not use Loops(doubly so for infinite loops), use First and Last with ignore Nulls instead.

Comment: could you post a code snippet? I am running into this issue and am and new to spark, and a detailed example would be really helpful thanks

Comment: @Megan, edited the answer for you to allow infinite loops.